# Wipe all text before colon (:) using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

```
webcategory.aspx?q=webcategory:Car&rows=0
```

From this querystring I'm extracting '`webcategory:Car`' (q) and inserts it into a textfield.

```
var qqry = $.getParamValue('q');    
if(qqry != '') {    
    $("#search-field").val(qqry)    
}
```

I need to know how to wipe all text before the colon(:) sign in the textfield using regex - So `webcategory:Car` becomes to just `Car`

Plz bear with me because my knowledge about regex are on an absolute minimum... :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be with regex?

```
$("#search-field").val(qqry.split(':').pop())
```

Comment: _"Does it have to be with regex?"_

Absolutly not - as long as it works... tnx a lot :-)

Comment: `.split().pop()` is a clever way of getting the last part.

Answer (score 1):

if there will only ever be a single colon you could skip regex al together and use the split() function like below:

```
var qqry = $.getParamValue('q');    
if(qqry != '') {    
     $("#search-field").val(qqry.split(":").pop())    
}
```

if there are potentially multiple colons you might have to go with a regex answer.

EDIT: 
as mentioned in other answers you can use the pop() function to pull of the last element in the array generated by split()

Comment: They're not semicolons. They're colons.

Comment: Also, it won't work when there is no colon, or when there are more than one colons.

Comment: i'm assuming as the question relates to colons then it was a fair assumption, added the pop() in an edit so the people who suggested it get the credit.  my bad...

Answer (score 1):

```
var afterColon = qqry.replace(/.*:/, "");
```

One benefit of doing this instead of the `split` option is that it will work even when there is no colon.

- "Car" => "Car"
- "webcategory:Car" => "Car"

Comment: Finally, official answer did not get rated